# Include enclosing tags in XPath selection

Tags: xpath

I have, for example, the following xml snippet

```
<rootnode>
    <level1 num="1">
        <level2 num="1">1.1</level2>
        <level2 num="2">1.2</level2>
        <level2 num="3">1.3</level2>
    </level1>
    <level1 num="2">
        <level2 num="1">2.1</level2>
        <level2 num="2">2.2</level2>
        <level2 num="3">2.3</level2>
        <level2 num="4">2.4</level2>
        <level2 num="5">2.5</level2>
    </level1>
    <level1 num="3">
        <level2 num="1">3.1</level2>
        <level2 num="2">3.2</level2>
        <level2 num="3">3.3</level2>
        <level2 num="4">3.4</level2>
    </level1>
</rootnode>
```

I want to select `level2` nodes which have `@num>3` together with their ancestors, i.e. to obtain

```
<rootnode>
    <level1 num="2">
        <level2 num="4">2.4</level2>
        <level2 num="5">2.5</level2>
    </level1>
    <level1 num="3">
        <level2 num="4">3.4</level2>
    </level1>
</rootnode>
```

The expression `//level1/level2[@num>3]`
yields

```
<level2 num="4">2.4</level2>
<level2 num="5">2.5</level2>
<level2 num="4">3.4</level2>
```

and `//level1/level2[@num>3]/ancestor::*`
yields all the ancestors, with their content :

```
<rootnode>
  <level1 num="1">
    <level2 num="1">1.1</level2>
    <level2 num="2">1.2</level2>
    <level2 num="3">1.3</level2>
  </level1>
<!-- ... 25 lines cut -->
```

I understand how these two expressions work and why they do not suit my needs.
What would be **the easiest way to achieve the desired result without xslt?**

The example is quite simple and in general *the selected nodes can be located arbitrarily deep*, and **the solution should scale**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this with pure XPath because XPath is a language for *selecting* existing nodes from an XML tree, whereas you want to *construct* a brand new tree that is different from the original one.  To build a new tree like this you need to use a higher-level tool like XSLT or XQuery, or a suitable XML manipulation library in a general purpose programming language.

Comment: Thanks @IanRoberts. I will have a look at XQuery then.